# HTML5 Canvas clipping and layer overlapping

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to clip two `shapes` (green and red) inside another `third` shape which is `circular`. It's working but for some reasons as you can see on this picture the `bottom left` and `top` edges are not smooth (zoom in).
[image]

I'm pretty sure it's because the `red shape` is under the `green shape` but at the same `position`. How can I avoid this pixel `overlapping` without moving the shape position.

Here is my code

```
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.scale(10,10)

function drawRounded(x,y,w,h,radius) {

  let K = (4/3)*Math.tan(Math.PI/8)
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius,y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w - radius,y)
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + w + radius*(K-1),y,x + w,y+radius*(1-K),x + w,y+radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w,y + h - radius)
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + w,y+ h + radius*(K-1),x + w + radius*(K-1),y+ h,x +w-radius,y+ h);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius,y + h)
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x+radius*(1-K),y+ h,x,y+ h+radius*(K-1),x,y+ h-radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x,y + radius)
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x,y+radius*(1-K),x+radius*(1-K),y,x+radius,y);

}

drawRounded(0,0,100,100,50)

ctx.clip();

ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,150);

ctx.fillStyle="#00FF00";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,80,80);
```

See my fiddle for testing [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/o9362msp/103/)

Comment: Stoop*d `clip`... It can't do antialiasing. Instead, use compositing. https://jsfiddle.net/o9362msp/106/

Comment: I see thanks for the answer